# Limiting concurrent outbound API triggered calls in Twilio Studio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We are building an outbound IVR that will receive a payload, in bulk, via REST API, and place an outbound call to the recipient. We are attempting to limit the number of concurrent flow executions, or calls placed at a time, to prevent transfers by the called parties from flooding the shared inbound queue. Is there any way to accomplish this internally to Twilio?

If my assumptions are correct, the limiting factors when placing outbound API calls via Twilio Studio are the inbound API queue, the number of concurrent flow executions, and the number of Calls Per Second (CPS).

My understanding is that the queued API requests are executed 30 at a time, on a FIFO basis- as one execution is completed, another begins.

Each execution can then place a call at a rate of no more than 1 CPS, so 30 seconds for all calls to be sent.

Is this correct?

Is there any means of throttling these executions, or outbound calls?

A CPS limitation would be ideal, however the minimum number is 1 CPS, which is still 3600 Calls Per Hour, far too many for this call center to handle. Can this be lowered to less than 1 CPS?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct, as far as I can tell, but Twilio is built to, within those limits, make the calls you want to make as fast as it can.

If you don't want to Twilio to place the outbound calls, you need to not send the API request to start the call until you are ready. You can do this by knowing the concurrency that you can handle in your own application and by subscribing to [call status webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/voice-webhooks#call-status-callbacks) so that you know when a call is complete and you can then place a new outbound call.